# What's the best way to format HTML, CSS and JavaScript code within a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to be able to put code in an ace editor div section. What's the best way to ignore the code so that I can easily put in in a string format?

I have tried multiple styles of quotes

```
      editorHTML.setValue('<html>
      <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>HTML5 canvas demo</title>

      </head>
      <body>
        <p>Canvas pane goes here:</p>
        <canvas id=pane width=300 height=200></canvas>
        <script>

        </script>
      </body>
    </html>');
     editorCSS.setValue('p {font-family: monospace;}
');
     editorJavaScript.setValue('var canvas = document.getElementById('pane');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

          context.fillStyle = 'rgb(250,0,0)';
          context.fillRect(10, 10, 55, 50);

          context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.5)';
          context.fillRect(30, 30, 55, 50);
');
```

This code doesn't work. I am assuming there is a really easy way to do it but after searching I cannot find it.

Comment: Please show code sample.

Comment: For some reason, the toolbar was blank when I uploaded it. The code is now there. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `\`` instead of `'` for multi-line strings, e.g. `.setValue(\` ... \`)`

Comment: It looks like the issue is with your editorJavScript.setValue function. You need to escape the single quotes of the JS being passed as a param.

Comment: That works. I can't believe I didn't try that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems there:

- JavaScript doesn't allow raw line breaks in string literals.
- Your last string is quoted with `'` but has unescaped `'`s inside it.

You have at least three options:

1. In modern JavaScript (ES2015+), you can use a template literal. Unescaped newlines are allowed in template literals. An untagged template literal creates a string.
2. You can escape the newlines with a backslash.
3. You can use string concatenation.

Example of #1:

```
editorHTML.setValue(`<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>HTML5 canvas demo</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Canvas pane goes here:</p>
    <canvas id=pane width=300 height=200></canvas>
    <script>

    </script>
  </body>
</html>`);
editorCSS.setValue(`p {font-family: monospace;} `);
editorJavaScript.setValue(`var canvas = document.getElementById("pane");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      context.fillStyle = "rgb(250,0,0)";
      context.fillRect(10, 10, 55, 50);

      context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.5)";
      context.fillRect(30, 30, 55, 50);
`);
```

Example of #2:

```
editorHTML.setValue('<html>\
  <head>\
    <meta charset=utf-8>\
    <title>HTML5 canvas demo</title>\
\
  </head>\
  <body>\
    <p>Canvas pane goes here:</p>\
    <canvas id=pane width=300 height=200></canvas>\
    <script>\
\
    </script>\
  </body>\
</html>');
editorCSS.setValue('p {font-family: monospace;} ');
editorJavaScript.setValue('var canvas = document.getElementById("pane");\
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");\
\
      context.fillStyle = "rgb(250,0,0)";\
      context.fillRect(10, 10, 55, 50);\
\
      context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.5)";\
      context.fillRect(30, 30, 55, 50);\
');
```

Example of #3:

```
editorHTML.setValue('<html>' +
  '<head>' +
    '<meta charset=utf-8>' +
    '<title>HTML5 canvas demo</title>' +
    '' +
  '</head>' +
  '<body>' +
    '<p>Canvas pane goes here:</p>' +
    '<canvas id=pane width=300 height=200></canvas>' +
    '<script>' +
    '' +
    '</script>' +
  '</body>' +
'</html>');
editorCSS.setValue('p {font-family: monospace;} ');
editorJavaScript.setValue('var canvas = document.getElementById("pane");' +
      'var context = canvas.getContext("2d");' +
      '' +
      'context.fillStyle = "rgb(250,0,0)";' +
      'context.fillRect(10, 10, 55, 50);' +
      '' +
      'context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 250, 0.5)";' +
      'context.fillRect(30, 30, 55, 50);'
);
```

Comment: Looks like example 1 is a little off - did you mean to put ` at the end of `</html>`?

Comment: @chazsolo - I missed *three* of them. Thanks!